# What publication published an early version of the Apple Monitor by Woz?

Tags: apple, reference-request

This is driving me nuts.  I am certain I have a downloaded scan of the source code to the 6502 ML monitor Woz wrote, but pre-dating Apple's use of the monitor.  I even remember there was some text like "a 6502 monitor you can use for your projects" or something to that effect.  It was published *somewhere* - maybe in Popular Electronics, or in a Homebrew newsletter, or a really early computer magazine...  But I'm drawing a total blank, and googling for '6502 and Woz and Monitor' isn't helping me at all.

Note, I am not referring to the code printed in the Red Book or subsequent Apple documentation.

Can anyone cite where the code for his 6502 ML monitor was first published?

Answer (score 19):

Ok, I found the image I had formed in my mind - it was from Dr. Dobbs Journal, Volume 1, Number 8, 1976. - But my memory was wrong about pre-dating Apple.  The article is actually titled "[A 6502 Disassembler from Apple by Steve Wozniak and Allen Baum](https://archive.org/details/dr_dobbs_journal_vol_01/page/n250/mode/2up)".

Comment: The apple floating point routines are in the previous issue.

Comment: I think I may have that in a box somewhere in the garage.  I'm pretty sure that it was in _Dr. Dobb's Journal of Computer Calisthenics & Orthodontia_ (the full name at the time: https://www.computerhistory.org/collections/catalog/102660981).  The motto was _Running Light without Over Byte_ or something like that

Comment: @Flydog57 if you follow the link in the answer, and go back [to the cover](https://archive.org/details/dr_dobbs_journal_vol_01/mode/2up), you’ll get confirmation ;-).